# How to blank input value if email exists

Tags: javascript, sql

I want to blank the input value if email exists else do not blank.
I tried this script but unable to blank in condition.
My script is

```
<script>
function checkemailAvailability() {
$("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "check_availability.php",
data:'emailid='+$("#emailid").val(),
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
$("#email-availability-status").html(data);
$("#emailid").val("");
$("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){}
});
}
</script>
```

My check_availability.php is

```
<?php 
include_once '../config/database.php';
//code check email
if(!empty($_POST["emailid"])) {
     $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $query = $db->query("SELECT email FROM login WHERE email='" . $_POST["emailid"] . "'");
        $query->execute();
    $r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($r>0)echo "<span style='color:red'>Email already exit</span>";
    else echo "<span style='color:green'>Email Available</span>";

}
?>
```

Please solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing any error in console?

Comment: There is no error. I just want blank input text if condition is email exists and else do not remove. But this code remove email in both condition.

Comment: @kishan: sure, because `success` of AJAX request is in both cases, when email exists or not.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX `success` returns true in both cases, when email address is available or not.

You need to test the value of AJAX answer and thene make a decision if the value should be blank or not.

check_availability.php (lines 11-12)

```
echo $r > 0 ? 'exists' : 'available';
```

JS

```
success:function(data){
    if (data === 'exists') {
        $("#email-availability-status").html('<span style="color:red">Email already exists</span>');
        $("#emailid").val("");
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    } else {
        $("#email-availability-status").html('<span style="color:green">Email Available</span>');
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
<?php 
include_once '../config/database.php';
$res = 1;
$msg = "<span style='color:green'>Email Available</span>";
if(!empty($_POST["emailid"]))
{
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();
    $query = $db->query("SELECT email FROM login WHERE email='" . $_POST["emailid"] . "'");
        $query->execute();
    $r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($r>0)
    {
        $res = 2;
        $msg = "<span style='color:red'>Email already exit</span>";
    }
}
echo json_encode(array( 'res'=>$res , 'msg'=>$msg ));
?>
```

JS

```
dataType : 'json',
success:function(data){
    $("#email-availability-status").html(data.msg);
    if( data.res == 2 )
        $("#emailid").val("");
    $("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
```

it will be better if you exchange data as json.
so you can pass multiple params in result if needed